# Change Table Row Color Based On Cell Value With jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't have much experience with jQuery, so I'm not sure how close I am to this. I have a table in my Rails app and I want the rows where the score.test_type value == true. (when it == true I have it display as the word "practice" if that matters) My table ID is scores and I have a CSS class of .score_table_color with a background-color. In my code below I don't reference score.test_type at all, which I'm not sure is an issue. Here is the jQuery code that I have so far

```
$(function(){
$("#scores tr").keyup(function() {
  var textValue = $(this).val();
  if(textValue == false){
    // add css class or any manipulation to your dom.
    $("#scores tr").addClass('score_table_color');
  }
 });
});
```

I have this pasted in the users.js file, because the table appears on the user's page. (the user has_many scores)

**UPDATE:**

I've updated my code to this:

```
$(function(){
$("#scores tr").ready(function() {
  var textValue = $(this).val();
  if(textValue == false){
    // add css class or any manipulation to your dom.
    $("#scores tr").addClass("score_table_color");
  }
 });
});
```

This makes the entire table blue. The problem with my code is that I seem to be saying that something in the table is false, not necessarily the score.test_type This is the way that cell is coded:

```
<td>
 <% if score.test_type == true %>
  <%= 'Practice' %>
 <% else %>
  <%= 'Actual' %>
 <% end %>      
</td>
```

Comment: Are you trying to compare textValue as a string? As in, it will contain either the word "true" or the word "false"

Comment: A table row will never have a value assigned. You would have to use a custom data attribute.

Comment: @eskimo The table data in that cell is score.test_type which is a boolean. I have the table display "practice or "actual" based on whether it is true or false. I want the whole row to be a color if it true vs.  false ("practice vs. "actual")

Comment: If you console.log(textValue) what does it give you? (on the line directly after you assign it)

Comment: I suspect you are are comparing a string in your if statement (which will always return true). If that is the case, wrap false in quotes: "false"

Comment: Do you have something input type inside your table ?

Comment: @eskimo in the td I have "if score.test_type == true "practice" else "actual"

Comment: @prp no inputs inside the table

Comment: What's the keyup event for? Is the user inputting text?

Comment: @eskimo no, I probably have the wrong syntax. I pieced together the code from what I could figure out online.

Comment: @eskimo I changed keyup to ready, and I edited the question above to give more info. I change the whole background color now, so it is reading the whole table as false. I need to specify that specific item has to be false.

Comment: Let's talk in the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61366/eskimo

Comment: @eskimo I have it working fine using just Ruby. Should I post the answer? (I'm happy to tell you what it is and have you post it, since you suggested it) The answer isn't really an answer to this question though, because I originally asked how to do it with jQuery. I don't know the standard Stack Overflow protocol in this situation.

Comment: @TonyTambe post your answer as an answer, I don't need any credit, you're the one who got it working ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just solving this using just Ruby instead of jQuery. (I'd still like to figure out how to get the jQuery to work properly. Here's how I made it work:

Below is the code showing the beginning of my loop that iterates through the user's scores to create the table. Al I really did was enclose the  in an if/else statement that says "if score.test_type == false, then apply the css class score_table_color, else just leave the  alone. Then my first  is the score.test_type, which is a boolean. If that is false, then the row background color changes based on my CSS.

```
<% @scores.order('taken_date').where.not(:name => 'ACT').each do |score| %>
    <% if score.test_type == false %>
        <tr class="score_table_color">
    <% else %>
        <tr>
    <% end %>

          <td>
            <% if score.test_type == true %>
              <%= 'Practice' %>
            <% else %>
              <%= 'Actual' %>
            <% end %>       
          </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer above definitely will work. But I like to post how I solved my own in a **Job Board** I created, so my answers will be a little detailed than just the task needed from the question, but my conclusion will strictly deal with using a simple `if..else` statement to answer the question.

**Firstly**

I defined a css to deal with my highlights, such that I have the following in my stylesheet pipeline:

```
/* For Row Highlighted */

.highlighted {
  background-color: #CFF3FF;
}
```

**Note**: You could use any color as you wish.

**Secondly**

I added a column to my already existing table with a Boolean data type, by running `rails g migration addHighlightedToJobs`. In my own case ***highlighted*** is my ColumnName, and ***Jobs*** is my TableName, such that my migration looks as this:

```
class AddHighlightedToJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :jobs, :highlighted, :boolean
  end
end
```

Then, I did run `rake db:migrate` to migrate my new migration.

**Note**: TableName must be *Plural*, if you are generating migrations as I have stated.

**Thirdly**

I added a check_box to my form just alternate between *true* and *false* when it is either checked or unckecked on my column name called highlighted

```
<%= f.check_box :highlighted %>
```

**Lastly**

To come to an answer to the question asked, since I have a check_box on my form, if checked, it posts to be ***true*** on my DB Table, and if unchecked, it posts to be ***false*** on my DB Table.

So, to change my table row color in my rails application, I used a simple `if..else` statement to call highlighted from my stylesheet with that such that I have:

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>

    <% if job.highlighted == true %>
      <section class="container">
        <div class="row jobs highlighted">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="font-size: 20px;"><strong><%= job.company_name %></strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="font-size: 20px;"><%= link_to(job.title, job) %></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-right" style="font-size: 20px; float: left;"><%= job.created_at.strftime('%d %B %y') %></div>
        </div>
      </section>
    <% else %>
      <section class="container">
        <div class="row jobs">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="font-size: 20px;"><strong><%= job.company_name %></strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="font-size: 20px;"><%= link_to(job.title, job) %></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-right" style="font-size: 20px; float: left;"><%= job.created_at.strftime('%d %B %y') %></div>
        </div>
      </section>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

I really believe my conclusion is DRY-which violates Rails Paradigm. We could rewrite it such that it becomes:

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
      <section class="container">
        <% if job.highlighted == true %>
          <div class="row jobs highlighted">
        <% else %>
          <div class="row jobs">
        <% end %>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="font-size: 20px;"><strong><%= job.company_name %></strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="font-size: 20px;"><%= link_to(job.title, job) %></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-right" style="font-size: 20px; float: left;"><%= job.created_at.strftime('%d %B %y') %></div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </section>
<% end %>
```